# Loading data onto HDFS using Sqoop

Tags: hdfs, sqoop, webhdfs, sqoop2

I was looking for ways to move data onto a HDFS system, wanted to know if Apache Sqoop can be used to pull/extract data from an external REST service?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to pull data from a REST service:

curl http:// | hdfs -put - /my/hdfs/directory

Answer (score 0):

From http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html

> Sqoop is a tool designed to transfer data between Hadoop and relational databases. You can use Sqoop to import data from a relational database management system (RDBMS) such as MySQL or Oracle into the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS), transform the data in Hadoop MapReduce, and then export the data back into an RDBMS.

So it doesn't support import data from REST service.